# EOFError in Fahrenheit, Celsius, Kelvin Conversion

Tags: python

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with the program I've written to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, Fahrenheit to Celsius, and Celsius to Kelvin. I'm assuming this has something to do with mixing int and str. I may be wrong.

```
def menu():
    print("Make a selection:")
    print("\n1. Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit")
    print("2. Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius")
    print("3. Convert Celsius to Kelvin")
    print("4. Exit")
    choice = int(raw_input("Enter your choice: "))
    return choice

def c(f):
    return str((f - 32) / 1.8)

def f(c):
    return str((c * 100) + 32)

def k(c):
    return str(c + 273.15)


def main():
    choice = menu()
    while choice != 4:
        if choice == 1:
            #convert C to F
            c = eval(raw_input("Enter Degrees Celsius: "))
            print(str(c) + "C = " + str(f)) + "F"
        elif choice == 2:
            #Convert F to C
            f = eval(raw_input("Enter Degrees Fahrenheit: "))
            print(str(f) + "F = " + str(c)) + "C"
        elif choice == 3:
            #Convert C to K
            k = eval(raw_input("Enter Degrees Celsius: "))
            print(str(c) + "C = " + str(k)) + "K"
        else:
            print('Invalid Entry!')
        choice = menu()
main()
```

My output is as follows when parsed online:

```
Make a selection:

1. Convert Celsius to Farenheit
2. Convert Farenheit to Celsius
3. Convert Celsius to Kelvin
4. Exit
Enter your choice: Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 39, in <module>
    main()
  Line 21, in main
    choice = menu()
  Line 7, in menu
    choice = int(raw_input("Enter your choice: "))
EOFError
```

Can you tell me what my error is? `int` & `str`? `raw_input` vs `input`?

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`?

Comment: @ChidG `raw_input()` is a Python builtin. See the manual.

Comment: Note that you never call the `c`, `f`, and `k` functions you define, but you do mask them and convert them to strings. Reread your assigned reading.

Comment: After they choose which conversion they want to make then I would like to prompt them to enter the temperature. I'm unsure how else to go about it besides using eval(raw_input("Enter degrees...")) This is not an assignment. I'm trying to figure this out on my own.

Comment: `raw_input` will return a string from the user in Python 2.x, but is not valid for Python 3.x.  In Python 3, `input` is standard.  What version are you using?

Comment: Thanks brandaemon. I'm taking a Python class through Coursera and they are using 2.7. I am trying to write this program by myself using the 3 literature. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Rename your functions to be different from your variables.**  If your conversion functions have the same names as your variables, Python 3 will give this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment
```

Python will interpret the letter to be a variable rather than a function.  In addition, you will have to include the function argument.  I changed the `f(c)` function to `foo(c)` and the `str(f)` to `str(foo(c))` and the program worked as expected.

Note that you're missing the ending `)` on some of your `print()` statements.  Parentheses are required for `print()` in Python 3.

Also note that the conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit should be `(c * 1.8) + 32`, not `(c * 100) + 32`.

Comment: The length of variable names has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That seemed to be the issue for me.  If I go back to one letter function names, the code doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is _unique_ variable names. The length has, again, _nothing_ to do with it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Right, that makes sense.  Fixed it.

Comment: I appreciate it brandaemon

Comment: @Perk8 I would appreciate an upvote and accept if this answer helped :)